# Keeping a WPF TableRow Element together over page break

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tablerow, flowdocument

I'm trying to print a table that could contain multiple pages of rows. The default behaviour of printing a FlowDocument with a table is that when a TableRow straddles between two pages it splits the row into two sections when the cell has multiple lines of text.

The problem is when there are cells where some are larger than others this can cause issues with borders prematurely closing for the shorter cells rather than flowing with the remainder of the row.

I'm looking to change the behaviour so that either all the cells become the same size, or that an entire row is moved down to the next page unless it can be fully rendered.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve the desired results by using the KeepTogether and KeepWithNext boolean variables (setting them to true) of the Paragraph object to ensure all the text in a cell remains together and forcing the Row to be pushed to the next page.

I don't know how I'd be able to achieve this with a mix of types but as I'm just using text this is good enough for my purposes.

Comment: Looks like KeepTogether is enough to achieve the desired behavior!